# Is there a recommended "safe" way to specify a bit-chord made out of constant flag-values?

Tags: c++, boolean, flags

The situation:  occasionally I write a function that can take a number of boolean parameters, and instead of writing something like this:

```
void MyFunc(bool useFoo, bool useBar, bool useBaz, bool useBlah);

[...]

// hard to tell what this means (requires looking at the .h file)
// not obvious if/when I got the argument-ordering wrong!
MyFunc(true, true, false, true);
```

I like to be able to specify them using a bit-chord of defined bits-indices, like this:

```
enum {
   MYARG_USE_FOO = 0,
   MYARG_USE_BAR,
   MYARG_USE_BAZ,
   MYARG_USE_BLAH,
   NUM_MYARGS
};

void MyFunc(unsigned int myArgsBitChord);

[...]

// easy to see what this means
// "argument" ordering doesn't matter
MyFunc((1<<MYARG_USE_FOO)|(1<<MYARG_USE_BAR)|(1<<MYARG_USE_BLAH));
```

That works fine, in that it allows me to pass around a lot of boolean arguments easily (as a single `unsigned long`, rather than a long list of separate bools), and I can easy see what my call to `MyFunc()` is specifying (without having to refer back to a separate header file).

It also allows me to iterate over the defined bits if I want to, which is sometimes useful:

```
unsigned int allDefinedBits = 0;
for (int i=0; i<NUM_MYARGS; i++) allDefinedBits |= (1<<i);
```

The main downsides are that it can be a bit error-prone.  In particular, it's easy to mess up and do this by mistake:

```
// This will compile but do the wrong thing at run-time!
void MyFunc(MYARG_USE_FOO | MYARG_USE_BAR | MYARG_USE_BLAH);
```

... or even to make this classic forehead-slapping mistake:

```
// This will compile but do the wrong thing at run-time!
void MyFunc((1<<MYARG_USE_FOO) | (1<<MYARG_USE_BAR) || (1<<MYARG_USE_BLAH));
```

My question is, is there a recommended "safer" way to do this?  i.e. one where I can still easily pass multiple defined booleans as a bit-chord in a single argument, and can iterate over the defined bit-values, but where "dumb mistakes" like the ones shown above will be caught by the compiler rather than causing unexpected behavior at runtime?

Comment: Usually the enum values are defined directly as powers of 2.

Comment: `MyFunc((1<<MYARG_USE_FOO)|(1<<MYARG_USE_BAR)|(1<<MYARG_USE_BLAH));` looks horrible to me. Why wouldn't you just assign different bit values to the enum values and avoid all the terrible shifts when you need to call the function. `enum { BIT_1 = 1<<0;, BIT_2 = 1<<1, bit_3=1<<2, etc...`

Comment: @RetiredNinja:  because if I do that, then I can't iterate over the bits' values anymore (or at least, not easily)

Comment: I guess if I had to decide between something that looked terrible and was hard to write everywhere and something that is "sometimes useful", I'd eliminate the terrible.

Comment: Sure, but instead of making tradeoffs, I'd like a solution that gives all the advantages at once :)

Comment: Best to craft the interface to how the client will use it.

Comment: @Tyker No. ['If the first enumerator does not have an initializer, the associated value is zero. For any other enumerator whose definition does not have an initializer, the associated value is the value of the previous enumerator plus one.'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a template...

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
constexpr unsigned int chordify(const T& v) {
    return (1 << v);
}

template <typename T1, typename... Ts>
constexpr unsigned int chordify(const T1& v1, const Ts&... rest) {
    return (1 << v1) | chordify(rest... );
}

enum {
   MYARG_USE_FOO = 0,
   MYARG_USE_BAR,
   MYARG_USE_BAZ,
   MYARG_USE_BLAH,
   NUM_MYARGS
};

int main() {
    static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(
        chordify(MYARG_USE_FOO, MYARG_USE_BAZ, MYARG_USE_BLAH)
    ));
    std::cout << chordify(MYARG_USE_FOO, MYARG_USE_BAZ, MYARG_USE_BLAH);
}
```

That outputs 13, and it's a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

enum class my_options_t : std::uint32_t {
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
    end
};

using my_options_value_t = std::underlying_type<my_options_t>::type;

inline constexpr auto operator|(my_options_t const & lhs, my_options_t const & rhs)
{
    return (1 << static_cast<my_options_value_t>(lhs)) | (1 << static_cast<my_options_value_t>(rhs));
}

inline constexpr auto operator|(my_options_value_t const & lhs, my_options_t const & rhs)
{
    return lhs | (1 << static_cast<my_options_value_t>(rhs));
}

inline constexpr auto operator&(my_options_value_t const & lhs, my_options_t const & rhs)
{
    return lhs & (1 << static_cast<my_options_value_t>(rhs));
}

void MyFunc(my_options_value_t options)
{
    if (options & my_options_t::bar)
        std::cout << "yay!\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    MyFunc(my_options_t::foo | my_options_t::bar | my_options_t::baz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit field, which allows you to efficiently construct a structure with individually-named bit flags.

for example, you could pass a `struct myOptions` to the function, where it is defined as:

```
struct myOptions {
  unsigned char foo:1;
  unsigned char bar:1;
  unsigned char baz:1;
};
```

Then, when you have to construct the values to send to the function, you'd do something like this:

```
myOptions opt;
opt.foo = 1;
opt.bar = 0;
opt.baz = 1;
MyFunct(opt);
```

Bit fields are compact and efficient, yet allow you to name the bits (or groups of bits) as if they were independent variables.

By the way, given the verbosity of the declaration, this is one place where I might break the common style of only declaring one variable per statement, and declare the struct as follows:

```
struct myOptions {
  unsigned char foo:1, bar:1, baz:1;
};
```

And, in C++20 you can add initializers:

```
struct myOptions {
  unsigned char foo:1{0}, bar:1{0}, baz:1{0};
}
```